# How to find out a file exists in the direcctory c#

Tags: c#, class, methods, directory, filepath

[file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2M9g.png)  [file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi1z3.png) I'm trying to pass my file's path to my method then I can get its text. I use the same structure of the code for like 10 other methods in the same project and it works properly. However, I send the correct path to my method and directory exists at location, It cannot find the file and open it and an error message comes up. I checked for every possible syntax errors, but could not find any and it only happens in one class of the project. Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? Maybe it is a visual studio bug that I don't know.

Here is the example of one out of two methods that cannot find the existing file:

```
public string ReadCourseInfoByID(string id)
    {
        string filepath = @"database\\Courses\\" + id + "\\Info.txt" ;
        //MessageBox.Show(filepath);
        string dataline=" ";
        if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File not found!", "Error");
            return dataline;
        }
        else
        {
           
            StreamReader InputFile;
            InputFile = File.OpenText(filepath);
            while (!InputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                 dataline= InputFile.ReadLine();
            }
            InputFile.Close();
            return dataline;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Note that `@"database\\Courses\\"` will be literally `"database\\Courses\\"`, with 2 ``\``

Comment: A path like the one you show (`database\Courses`) is a *relative path*. That means that it's relative to whatever the current directory is. If the current directory is different, then the path will point to a different location

Comment: I tried with one "\" but still does not find the existing file. The error is directory not found exception which I use message box showing "File not found!"

Comment: To check the real absolute path use something like `var absolutPath = Path.GetFullPath(filepath );` it will give you the real path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `File.Exists` not `Directory.Exists` to check if a file exist.

```
if (!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found!", "Error");
    return dataline;
}
else...
```

Answer (score 1):

As Cid commented, you're using a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim), denoted by the @ prefix of your string. The escape character for a verbatim string isn't `\` but `"`, meaning you don't need to escape backslashes to have them inside your string. This turns your current path into this

`string filepath = @"database\Courses\" + id + @"\Info.txt"`

Or more simply, using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) this

`string filepath = $@"database\Courses\{id}\Info.txt"`

---

Note that it is **not** recommended to do filepath concatenation manually like this. Instead use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) method to do it for you. This once again turns your code into this

`string filepath = Path.Combine("database", "Courses", id, "Info.txt");`

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zj9VMx)'s a dotnetfiddle demonstrating this entire behaivour. Note the paths aren't the same as on a windows system, but that's due to the way dotnetfiddle works

---

Please also note that all these file paths are [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths), meaning the actual location it points to is different depending on where you are executing your application. If you start it in `C:\Program Files\` the path will point to `C:\Program Files\database\Courses\{id}\Info.txt`, but if you start it in another location, like `C:\Temp\` the path will actually point to `C:\Temp\database\Courses\{id}\Info.txt`